# PHP - Loop inside loop second loop runs only once

Tags: php

I'm running one while inside another while but the second one is running only one time why and how can I fix it. I have also try with for but running again only once.

```
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT season FROM search WHERE link = '$getid' Order by id asc";
$result = mysql_query($sql, $conn) or trigger_error("SQL", E_USER_ERROR);
while ($list = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $season = $list['season'];
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM search WHERE link = '$getid' and season = '$season'");
    $episodes = mysql_num_rows($sql);
    echo '1st';
    $sqls = "SELECT * FROM search WHERE link = '$getid' and season = '$season' Order by id asc";
    $results = mysql_query($sqls, $conn) or trigger_error("SQL", E_USER_ERROR);
    while ($lists = mysql_fetch_assoc($results))
    {
        $episode = $lists['episode'];
        echo'2nd';
    }
}
```

Comment: you should really place your mysql_fetch_assoc outside of the condition to improve performance as each time it loops, mysql_fetch_assoc is being evaluate every times. but i'm sure that's not the real problem though.

Comment: Do you have more than one row which matching $results. check number of rows of $results also.
Note: Now its time to go to mysqli @lmBigNoob

Comment: what's the value of $episodes?

Answer (score 3):

You are overriding the variables, use different ones:

```
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT season FROM search WHERE link = '$getid' Order by id asc";
$result = mysql_query($sql, $conn) or trigger_error("SQL", E_USER_ERROR);
while ($list = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $season = $list['season'];
    $sql2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM search WHERE link = '$getid' and season = '$season'");
    $episodes = mysql_num_rows($sql2);
    echo '1st';
    $sqls = "SELECT * FROM search WHERE link = '$getid' and season = '$season' Order by id asc";
    $results2 = mysql_query($sqls, $conn) or trigger_error("SQL", E_USER_ERROR);
    while ($lists2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($results2))
    {
        $episode = $list2['episode'];
        echo'2nd';
    }
}
```

Comment: No thats not the proble take a look better I dont ovverriding the variables